# Crypto is not support python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

when I use python3.x , run code:

```
    with open('rsa_public_key.pem') as f:
    key = f.read()
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
    cipher = Cipher_pkcs1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
    cipher_text = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(aes_key))
    str1 = cipher_text
```

it will raise an error:

```
  File "de_test.py", line 81, in get_login_data_inputPostString
cipher_text = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(aes_key))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 137, in encrypt
em = b('\x00\x02') + ps + bchr(0x00) + message
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

But when I use python 2.6 , it will pass.

so crypto is not support python 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the `aes_key`, it looks like you're trying to pass a `str` object where you should be passing a `bytes` object to `encrypt()`.